# How firing of neurons stimulate reality?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroimaging, brain, neurology

Iam  just an enthusiast.When I look for how does our brain works it boils down to firing of neurons in a pattern. I read that  all of our thoughts, memory is due to firing of networks of neurons in a pattern. But one thing I just could not correlate is that how firing of neurons using electrical signals picturises the world around and beyond us? .How these electrical signals did it appears to us recognizably as something like sound, picture etc...

How neurons firing in a pattern just could appear it as reality or something else ?

Comment: The thing you are asking about is called the "hard problem of consciousness" - there are many theories, which you can find if you search here using those terms, but no certain answer.

Comment: Seems we just had this same question asked last month: [How a living being (a huge collection of atoms) perceive things?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/25028/7001)

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg and BryanKrause thanks